# $\iint \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}dxdy$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I need to know how $\int \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}dxdy$ can be solved! Unfortunately the calculation didn't work on this question.

I have no ideas!

It's a double by the way.

Comment: It would be hard to apply (spherical) variable transformations without any integral bounds

Comment: I do not know a meaning for an indefinite double integral.  Since the tag says `definite-integrals`, please show your region of integration.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As people stated in the comments your question didn't ask well.

However you can simply use Mathematica Wolfram to solve this calculus problem or even see the steps.

However the result for indefinite integral for evaluation is:

\begin{align*}
&\int\int \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} \,dx\,dy \\
&= c_1x + c_2 - \frac{1}{2}x \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \log\left(1 - \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}\right) \\
&\quad \\
&\quad + \frac{1}{2}x \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \log\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} + 1\right) \\
&\quad + y \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \log\left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} + x\right) \\
&\quad - z \sqrt{\frac{1}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2} \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{xy}{z\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}\right)
\end{align*}

The code is:

`Integrate[Sqrt[1/(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)], x, y]`

However you can use Wolfram alpha too!

Comment: Thanks it helped me!

Comment: @argo indefinite multiple integrals are not well defined objects. Consider that if I had used a polar coordinates transformation to the integrand, the "indefinite integral" I would have gotten would have been $$\iint \frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}drd\theta = \int \sqrt{r^2+z^2}+C_rd\theta$$ $$= \theta(\sqrt{r^2+z^2}+C_r)+C_\theta = \tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}(\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}+C_r)+C_\theta$$ which is not equivalent to doing the repeated integration in Cartesian coordinates. This proves that indefinite multiple integrals don't exist and don't make sense to talk about.